# Bing Ads API, how to find CustomerAccountId

Tags: bing-ads-api

I'm trying to use `SubmitGenerateReport` to generate an [AdGroupPerformanceReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/adgroupperformancereportrequest?view=bingads-13) and it looks like I need to add both a `CustomerId` and a `CustomerAccountId` to the header in addition to the `DeveloperToken` and `AuthenticationToken` that I needed for the other endpoints.

I'm pretty sure the `CustomerId` is the same `CustomerId` that I get back from the getUser endpoint, but what is a `CustomerAccountId` and where can I find it?

Or am looking at the wrong thing and the problem with my request is not that it's missing the `CustomerAccountId`?

Answer (score 0):

It was something else, you can just leave the CustomerAccountId as null.